# Is there anyway to get a next text element from HTML with Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

Hi I'm trying to find"FIND THIS" to "GET THIS" in below HTML.

```
a= '''<tr>
<td colspan="2" width="268">
<span style="width:268px;font-size:10pt;">FIND THIS</span>
</td>
<td colspan="2" width="332">
<span class="xforms_input" style="width:332px;font-size:10pt;">GET THIS</span>
</td>
</tr>'''

b = a.find('span', text = "FIND THIS").next_element.next_element.next_element.next_element.next_element.next_element.next_element
```

I was able to get "GET THIS" by finding "FIND THIS" and then using next_element for 7 times.

Is there any other way to get "GET THIS" text ? (I tried to use parent.parent.next_sibling.children, but somehow it didn't work.)

I also want to know whether there's any way to get a next text element without using parent or next_element code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one approach by finding the `parent`

**Ex:**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

a= '''<tr>
<td colspan="2" width="268">
<span style="width:268px;font-size:10pt;">FIND THIS</span>
</td>
<td colspan="2" width="332">
<span class="xforms_input" style="width:332px;font-size:10pt;">GET THIS</span>
</td>
</tr>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(a, "html.parser")
print(soup.find('span', text = "FIND THIS").find_parent('tr').find('span', text = "GET THIS"))

# OR if you do not know what the text is use the class
print(soup.find('span', text = "FIND THIS").find_parent('tr').find('span', class_ = "xforms_input"))
```

**Output:**

```
<span class="xforms_input" style="width:332px;font-size:10pt;">GET THIS</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're working with HTML I think you will be better of using the [HTML Parser](https://docs.python.org/3/library/html.parser.html) module

This code is taken from the python docs

```
from HTMLParser import HTMLParser

# create a subclass and override the handler methods
class MyHTMLParser(HTMLParser):
    def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
        print "Encountered a start tag:", tag
    def handle_endtag(self, tag):
        print "Encountered an end tag :", tag
    def handle_data(self, data):
        print "Encountered some data  :", data

# instantiate the parser and fed it some HTML
parser = MyHTMLParser()
parser.feed('<html><head><title>Test</title></head>'
            '<body><h1>Parse me!</h1></body></html>')
```

Here is the result:

```
Encountered a start tag: html
Encountered a start tag: head
Encountered a start tag: title
Encountered some data  : Test
Encountered an end tag : title
Encountered an end tag : head
Encountered a start tag: body
Encountered a start tag: h1
Encountered some data  : Parse me!
Encountered an end tag : h1
Encountered an end tag : body
Encountered an end tag : html
```

I think you can loop up the data and then iterate forward until you find the second text.